# Show link in Bootstrap 4 collapse

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

So I have something like this in Bootstrap 4:

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse">
collapsed text
</div>
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">more / less</a>
```

It works fine, however, the link "more / less" is not shown as a link and not in the color as all the other links. It is just shown as a text. How can I make it to look like any other link on my website? Thanks.

Comment: Add `href="#"` to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use CSS in order to achieve that.

```css
.collapse-link {
  color: blue !important;
  text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.collapse-link:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

However, the `!important` clause should be avoided if possible. What I can suggest is using the Bootstrap buttons instead of an anchor.

```html
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">Button</button>
```

Edit: or just add `href="#"` to your anchor like @ZimSystem said.